# TernJS for Vim loading EmberJS

Tags: vim, tern

I am trying to use ternJS to autocomplete the ember library. I want to be able to do Ember. and see a list of all the functions and or properties. Here is what I have in my .tern-project file

```
{
    "libs": [
        "browser",
        "underscore",
        "jquery"
    ],
    "loadEagerly": ["bower_components/ember/*.js"]
    "plugins": {
        "node": {}
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to load just the debug version (ember.debug.js) as your config is loading several times the different ember-runtimes.

My config (still not very functional though, as the docs are not being loaded):

```
{
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "libs": [
    "browser",
    "jquery"
  ],
  "loadEagerly": [
    "bower_components/ember/ember.debug.js"
  ]
}
```

p.s.: I've aborted this config, as ternJS started consuming my CPU a lot. Something might have triggered that behaviour, but didn't have time to debug it. Erased ternJS plugin from my poor CPU and Atom